# How to upload Arduino C code to mBot?

Tags: arduino-ide, mbot

I am trying to program [mBot](https://www.makeblock.com/steam-kits/mbot) using Arduino IDE. I am connected to the mBot using USB on `COM7`, I am able to upload a code created in [mBlock 3.4.11](http://www.mblock.cc/software-1/mblock/mblock3/) fine, using "Arduino Mode" as the editing mode. I would like to proceed to more complex coding now and for this I want to be able to edit the source code directly. The source code seen in the MBlock application seems to be read only, there is a button which should allow editing the code, called "Edit with Arduino". When I press this button, the Arduino IDE opens and I am able to edit the code. The trouble is I seem to be unable to send the code edited this way into the mBot.

When I use the Arduino IDE Sketch/Upload menu item, the code is compiled, but when sending it, I always get following error:

> avrdude: stk500v2_ReceiveMessage(): timeout

Note: I was editing and uploading Arduino code before with both Ardino IDE and VisualStudio visualMicro (now [Arduino IDE for Visual Studio](https://www.visualmicro.com/)) without any issues.

I do not know exactly how is the mBlock application handling the upload, but while doing so a folder with the project is created, which contains the following buildprefs.txt - perhaps this could help to understand what it is doing:

```
build.arch = AVR
build.board = AVR_UNO
build.core = arduino
build.core.path = X:\Users\UserName\mblockExe\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\cores\arduino
build.extra_flags = 
build.f_cpu = 16000000L
build.mcu = atmega328p
build.path = X:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\build3998294614124133332.tmp
build.project_name = project_followLineAuto0_0.cpp
build.source.path = X:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\com.makeblock.Scratch3.4.11\Local Store\scratchTemp\project_followLineAuto0_0
build.system.path = X:\Users\UserName\mblockExe\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\system
build.usb_flags = -DUSB_VID={build.vid} -DUSB_PID={build.pid} '-DUSB_MANUFACTURER={build.usb_manufacturer}' '-DUSB_PRODUCT={build.usb_product}'
build.usb_manufacturer = "Unknown"
build.variant = standard
build.variant.path = X:\Users\UserName\mblockExe\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\variants\standard
build.verbose = true
build.warn_data_percentage = 75
compiler.S.extra_flags = 
compiler.S.flags = -c -g -x assembler-with-cpp
compiler.ar.cmd = avr-ar
compiler.ar.extra_flags = 
compiler.ar.flags = rcs
compiler.c.cmd = avr-gcc
compiler.c.elf.cmd = avr-gcc
compiler.c.elf.extra_flags = 
compiler.c.elf.flags = {compiler.warning_flags} -Os -Wl,--gc-sections
compiler.c.extra_flags = 
compiler.c.flags = -c -g -Os {compiler.warning_flags} -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD
compiler.cpp.cmd = avr-g++
compiler.cpp.extra_flags = 
compiler.cpp.flags = -c -g -Os {compiler.warning_flags} -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD
compiler.elf2hex.cmd = avr-objcopy
compiler.elf2hex.extra_flags = 
compiler.elf2hex.flags = -O ihex -R .eeprom
compiler.ldflags = 
compiler.objcopy.cmd = avr-objcopy
compiler.objcopy.eep.extra_flags = 
compiler.objcopy.eep.flags = -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0
compiler.path = {runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path}/bin/
compiler.size.cmd = avr-size
compiler.warning_flags = -w
compiler.warning_flags.all = -Wall -Wextra
compiler.warning_flags.default = 
compiler.warning_flags.more = -Wall
compiler.warning_flags.none = -w
```

Comment: Which Arduino IDE do you use? How did you get it? Which operating system? May we see the code (just curious)?

Comment: @Jot The Arduino IDE is installed by the mBlock application. The version I have is 1.6.5. I am running Windows 10 x64 Pro.

Comment: That is an old version. The newest version is 1.8.8. Here is more information about mBot: https://github.com/Makeblock-official/mBot The schematic is in the "pcb" folder. As far as I can tell the hardware and software of the mBot is okay, they know what they are doing. You could buy a cheap uno clone for 3 dollars to learn more about c++ arduino programming.

Comment: "That is an old version. The newest version is 1.8.8". Well, that is a version which is bundled with mBlocks. As it is working fine, I am not sure if it is worth messing with the installation. Regarding the C++ arduino programming, I already have experience with that (I own one Uno and one Mega board). I only had trouble making the C code working with the mBot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to select correct board (Arduino UNO) and port.

See this guide for details: 
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoUno#toc5